# Error installing Sony Remote Play

Tags: windows-7, ps3

I'm trying to install Remote Play software to connect my laptop to my PS3.  I've found a guide with instructions which seem to be in fairly wide use (found similar walk-throughs on numerous other sites), for running the software on a non-Vaio PC.

[Tech-Recipies:  Playstation 3 – Use Remote Play on any Windows 7 PC](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/7225/playstation-3-use-remote-play-on-any-non-sony-vaio-windows-7-pc-ps3-firmware-3-30/)

The setup essentially goes like this:

1. Download Remote Play software.
2. Download patch by NTAuthority.
3. Install Remote Play as normal.
4. Reboot.
5. Extract NTAuthority patch to Remote Play program folder.
6. Manually register patched DLLs via CLI.
7. Run Remote Play software.

Sadly, my problem is early in - Step 3.  I had to use Google to find the software download, as the link from Tech-Recipies seems broken.  I found the download on Sony's site here:

[Sony eSupport:  Remote Play with PlayStation®3](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-download.pl?upd_id=6135&SMB=YES)

After downloading and running the software, I hit "Next" at the welcome screen and "I Agree" at the EULA screen.  After this, a popup informs me that Setup is checking my computer's information.  Then, Setup terminates with this error:

[image: Information - This update can only run on Microsoft Windows Vista, Microsoft Windows 7]

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Is anyone familiar with this error in this software?  Is there a way to work around it?  Did I perhaps pick the wrong download from Sony's site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems "wrong download" indeed was the problem.  After a little bit more Googling, I found another article with similar instructions, but a different download link for the Remote Play software.

[PS3 Hacks - VAIO Remote Play Patch Released: Use Sony’s Remote Play on non-VAIO PCs](http://ps3.dashhacks.com/2010/06/21/vaio-remote-play-patch-released-use-sonys-remote-play-on-non-vaio-pcs)

The download link for [VAIO Remote Play](http://www.ps3-hacks.com/file/80) on that site actually points to the same site that hosts the NTAuthority patch.  However, the EXE file is signed by Sony and scans clean on VirusTotal.

After installing the software and applying the patch per the instructions on the site, everything's running fine.